# I am using the Smart Subscriber button and using customid parameter, but not getting in return

Tags: javascript, paypal, payment, sandbox, subscription

This is part of my PayPal smart subscription button script from sandbox environment. I am using the "custom_id" parameter for Identification, but not receiving in return in the IPN listener.

```
createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.subscription.create({
    /* Creates the subscription */
    plan_id: 'P-PlanId',
    quantity: 5,    
    custom_id:101
    
    });
```

Comment: can you provide an example of your output?  Perhaps even how you are using it ?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using IPN? That is a very old and clunky service that predates the existence of the current subscriptions API by ~20 years.

For current Subscription integrations, [use Webhooks.](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions) The PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED event is of particular interest.

Comment: Can you share any Sample code or documentation for Webhooks implementation in Dot Net

Comment: A webhook listener can be implemented on any HTTPS webserver, with any language. The guide for PayPal webhooks is at https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have changed my implementation to accept webhook notification. But I am always getting false value while validating it with Paypal using this c# code isValid = WebhookEvent.ValidateReceivedEvent(apiContext, nvc, requestBody, webhookId);

Comment: Finally I got it working, The issue was webhookId passed while validating the notification. The id we need to pass is the id created in paypal site, not the webhook event id we are receiving in the notification.

Comment: Why use IPN? Because PayPal, like always, do things very badly. Webhooks DOES NOT work for PayPal Smart Payment buttons nor any other ready-to-use button.

To use Webhook, you have to create an app and then find on Google a way to create a button (because PayPal has only small docs with a node.js code)

I integrated Stripe, Cryptos, 2Checkout, Rapid, Verifone, and more, and I never saw a service soo bad as PP for the users and so bad for developers. Incredible and frustrating but I'm happy the best days of PayPal are in the past.

Comment: PayPal Subscription buttons documentation is at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/ , and you can generate one in an account at https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans .  For one-time payments, a backend is required now, the node.js code is an example but any environment can be used

Comment: Webhooks should be created with the same App Client-Id as the subscriptions are being processed. IPN should not be used.